# C struct member pointer in shared memory (mmap)

Tags: c, dynamic, process, shared-memory, mmap

I have two processes that access the same shared memory. However I want to store a dynamically allocated array in shared memory. I know this can be achieved using flexible array members but I am not allowed to use them.

I am able to allocate and access the dynamic array from the server but whenever my client attempts to access it I get a segfault. I can access other structure members just fine nontheless. Here is the logic of my code. I allocated some extra space at the end of the shared memory segment and set the array to point to the end of the segment.

```
struct A{
    int a;
    struct B *other;
}
struct B{
    int b;
}
...
//Server
fd=shm_open("shared", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
ftruncate(fd, sizeof(struct A)+200*sizeof(struct B));
struct A *ptr=mmap(NULL, sizeof(struct A)+200*sizeof(struct B), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
ptr->other=(struct B *)(ptr+1);       
int i=0;
for(i=0;i<200;i++){
    struct B b;
    ptr->other[i]=b;
}
...
//Client
int fd=shm_open("shared", O_RDWR, 0666);
struct A *ptr=mmap(NULL, sizeof(struct A)+200*sizeof(struct B), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
printf("%i", ptr->other[0]);// SEGFAULT
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The shared memory will usually be mapped at different addresses in different processes. You can't pass pointers between the processes, but you can instead pass offsets from the beginning of the shared memory.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working by discarding the other pointer inside my A struct and simply doing struct B *other=(struct B *)(ptr+1) in both the client and server.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to define the other list outside the structure

```
struct A{
    int a;
}
struct B{
    int b;
}
...
//Server
fd=shm_open("shared", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
ftruncate(fd, sizeof(struct A)+200*sizeof(struct B));
struct A *ptr=mmap(NULL, sizeof(struct A)+200*sizeof(struct B), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
struct B *other=(struct B *)(ptr+1);      
int i=0;
for(i=0;i<200;i++){
    struct B b;
    other[i]=b;
}
...
//Client
int fd=shm_open("shared", O_RDWR, 0666);
struct A *ptr=mmap(NULL, sizeof(struct A)+200*sizeof(struct B), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
struct B *other=(struct B *)(ptr+1); 
printf("%i", other[0]);
```